# for loop to match columns

Tags: r

I have two different data sets, A and B, which are of different lengths and I need to add a column from B to the end of A if the dates match up. Here is what the dataset B looks like:

```
 Variable_1    Variable_2       Date         Variable_3
 v1             v2          10/12/2014        0
 v1a            v2a         10/11/2014        18
 v1b            v2b         10/10/2014        15
 v1c            v2c         10/08/2014        0
 v1d            v2d         10/09/2014        0
 v1e            v2e         10/01/2014        0
```

A:

```
 Date              Variable_4         Variable_5    Variable_0
 10/11/2014          v4                v5            N
 10/12/2014          v4a              v5a            N
 10/08/2014          v4b              v5b            N
 10/09/2014          v4c              v5c            N
 10/25/2014          v4d              v5d            N
 10/31/2014          v4e              v5e            N
```

So I need a loop that says if Date in A in same as Date in B then add Variable_3 to Dataset A.

So after the loop is finished it should look like:

```
 Date              Variable_4         Variable_5      Variable_0
 10/11/2014          v4                v5              18 
 10/12/2014          v4a              v5a              0
 10/08/2014          v4b              v5b              0
 10/09/2014          v4c              v5c              0
 10/25/2014          v4d              v5d              N
 10/31/2014          v4e              v5e              N
```

Currently I have this loop but it doesn't seem to be working?

```
   lgthWeather <- length(Park$PRCP)
   lgthData <- length(Data$Date)
   count <- 0 


    #### broken loop ###

for(i in 1:lgthWeather)
{
  for(j in 1:lgthData)
  {
    if(Data$Date[j] == Park$Date[i])
    {
      Data$Precip[j] <- Park$PRCP[i] 
      j <- j + 1 
    }
    if(Data$Date[j] != Park$PRCP[i])
    {
      j <- j + 1
    }
  }
i <- i + 1 
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

SOLUTION BELOW:

```
    merge(A, B[,c("Date","Variable_3")], by="Date", all.x=TRUE)

    Date Variable_4 Variable_5 Variable_0 Variable_3
    1 10/08/2014        v4b        v5b          N          0
    2 10/09/2014        v4c        v5c          N          0
    3 10/11/2014         v4         v5          N         18
    4 10/12/2014        v4a        v5a          N          0
    5 10/25/2014        v4d        v5d          N         NA
    6 10/31/2014        v4e        v5e          N         NA
```

Comment: Or you could use `left_join(A,B[,c("Date", "Variable_3")], by='Date')` from `library(dplyr)`

Comment: instead of adding 'SOLVED' to your title, why don't you accept one of the answers provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `merge` will do what you're looking for:

```
merge(A, B[,c("Date","Variable_3")], by="Date", all.x=TRUE)

        Date Variable_4 Variable_5 Variable_0 Variable_3
1 10/08/2014        v4b        v5b          N          0
2 10/09/2014        v4c        v5c          N          0
3 10/11/2014         v4         v5          N         18
4 10/12/2014        v4a        v5a          N          0
5 10/25/2014        v4d        v5d          N         NA
6 10/31/2014        v4e        v5e          N         NA
```

Comment: I get the error:                                                Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column. Both of my date variables are of type "integer"

Comment: It looks like you're specifying a column name that doesn't exist in the second data frame in your call to `merge`. Please post the actual code you ran.

Answer (score 2):

Since your dates are unique, you could use a vector subset with `match`.

```
A$Variable_3 <- B$Variable_3[match(A$Date, B$Date)]
A[order(A$Date),]
#         Date Variable_4 Variable_5 Variable_0 Variable_3
# 3 10/08/2014        v4b        v5b          N          0
# 4 10/09/2014        v4c        v5c          N          0
# 1 10/11/2014         v4         v5          N         18
# 2 10/12/2014        v4a        v5a          N          0
# 5 10/25/2014        v4d        v5d          N         NA
# 6 10/31/2014        v4e        v5e          N         NA
```